# How to get score list from zset in redis

Tags: redis

**Is it possible to get all the keys from the zset collection?**

I need to create a key search. The keys have the form id0+id1+id2. Need to get all records with id0 equal to a certain key or id1 equal to another key. Since I can't always use zrangebyscore, I need to get all the keys and filter them on the client.

Comment: https://redis.io/commands/zrange?

Comment: zrange returns the range of elements. I need a range of keys.

Comment: What's a range of keys? Is that not a set of elements without a score, you can remove the score in your application code.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's possible in Redis Version 6.2.0

Redis has introduced a new command called `ZUNION`, you can use this command to get keys of zset.

https://redis.io/commands/zunion

```
ZUNION numkeys key [key ...] [WEIGHTS weight [weight ...]] [AGGREGATE SUM|MIN|MAX] [WITHSCORES]
```

By default, it returns you only keys but you can get keys along with score as well if you want so.

```
127.0.0.1:6380> ZADD zset2 100 test
(integer) 1
127.0.0.1:6380> ZUNION 1 zset2
1) "test"
127.0.0.1:6380>
```